# Error when compiling with GCC

Tags: c, function, gcc, reference, undefined

Every time I compile I get the following error message:

```
Undefined reference to ( function name )
```

Let's say I have three files: `Main.c`, `printhello.h`, `printhello.c`. `Main.c` calls function `print_hello()`, which returns "Hello World". The function is defined in `printhello.c`.

Now, here's the following code of printhello.h:

```
#ifndef PRINTHELLO_H 
#define PRINTHELLO_H

void print_hello();

#endif
```

I am sure this code is fine. I still don't know why is it giving me the error, though. Can you help me?

Comment: What does your main.c look like? What is your compiler command line?

Comment: We need a little more information. What are you trying to compile? If you are calling print_hello in Main.c, make sure that you have `#include "printhello.h"` in the file.

Comment: FWIW, this is a _linker_, not compiler, error.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined references are the linker errors. Are you compiling and linking all the source files ? Since the main.c calls `print_hello()`, linker should see the definition of it.

```
gcc Main.c printhello.c -o a.out
```

Comment: Oh, right, forgot that. Main.c code is: #include "printhello.h" int main { printhello(); return 0; }

Comment: @Alex - Just including a header file, doesn't compile it's source file. By including the header file, pre-processor just copies the contents of it to the `Main.c`. You should explicitly say to the compiler to compile `printhello.c` also.

Comment: @Alex - Now the linker can see the definitions in `printhello.o` and link to it to give the final execuatable `a.out`. Also " print_hello(), which returns "Hello World" ", the usage of word **returns** is wrong. The return type of `printhello()` is **void**. The function just prints `Hello World` while returning nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The error is, I think, a linker error rather than a compiler error; it is trying to tell you that you've not provided all the functions that are needed to make a complete program.

You need to compile the program like this:

```
gcc -o printhello Main.c printhello.c
```

This assumes that your file `Main.c` is something like:

```
#include "printhello.h"

int main(void)
{
    print_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

and that your file `printhello.c` is something like:

```
#include "printhello.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello World");
}
```

Your declaration in `printhello.h` should be:

```
void print_hello(void);
```

This explicitly says that the function takes no parameters.  The declaration with the empty brackets means "there is a function `print_hello()` which returns no value and takes an indeterminate (but not variadic) list of arguments", which is quite different.  In particular, you could call `print_hello()` with any number of arguments and the compiler could not reject the program.

Note that C++ treats the empty argument list the same as `void print_hello(void);` (so it would ensure that calls to `print_hello()` include no arguments), but C++ is not the same as C.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to explicitly build object files for the printhello:

```
gcc -c printhello.c -o printhello.o
gcc -o Main main.c printhello.o
```

This has the added benefit of allowing other programs to use the print_hello method

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is from the linker and not the compiler. You need to compile and link both the source files. I think what you are doing is simply including the header file in `Main.c` and you are not compiling the `printhello.c`

You need to :

`gcc Main.c printhello.c -o myprog`

or

construct the object files first

```
gcc -c printhello.c
gcc -c Main.c
```

then link them

```
gcc Main.o printhello.o
```